# multiprocessing Queue subclass issue

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to subclass multiprocessing.Queue for implementing processes to grab chunks of the queue.  The only problem is, I'm getting a weird TypeError?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#whaaaaa!?

from multiprocessing import Queue

class BufferQueue(Queue):
    '''A thread/process safe queue for append/popleft operations with the import
    buffer.'''

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BufferQueue,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def consume(self, lim):
        '''Consume up to but no more than lim elements and return them in a new
        list, cleaning up the buffer.

        @params
        lim -- the maximum (limit) to consume from the list.  If less items
        exist in the list then that's fine too.
        '''
        lim = len(queue) if len(queue) < lim else lim
        return [self.popleft() for i in range(lim)]
```

testing this (I split this out so that I wasn't pulling in anything else)

```
| => ./tests/wtf_queue.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tests/wtf_queue.py", line 10, in <module>
    class BufferQueue(Queue):
TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

Edit/Update:

Comment: how are you initializing the queue?

Comment: I'm not.  What you see is the entire test.  I'm not actually calling or using it in any way.

Comment: I'm thinking this has got to be something to do with the way that multiprocessing.Queue handles local/shared resources?  calling the class specification during JIT loading as a TypeDef means that something in core is getting munged up AFAICT

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`multiprocessing.Queue` is a method that creates queues, so you're supposed to use it as a function `my_queue = Queue()`.

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Queue
>>> type(Queue)
<class 'method'>
```

As you can see is not a 'type', which you would use to subclass.

If you want to implement your own queue, you could take a look at [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/queue.html#queue.Queue)

**EDIT:**

If you want to subclass the queue from multiprocessing, use `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` instead, which is the type of the object returned by `multiprocessing.Queue()`

Comment: Yeah the docs need to do something about this.  it is specifically called a class in the documentation, and in addition the function returns a class.  Then, on top of that, queue.Queue doesn't get serialized and is thus not useful for multiprocessing.  The processes that pushes onto the queue is in a completely different interpreter than the one that consumes it.

Comment: Testing this now to see if it works or breaks.  I have my doubts that doing this will work.

Comment: extending multiprocessing.queues.Queue and then instantiating it in the processes manager context seems to be working  (    queue = BufferQueue(ctx=get_context()) )